# Most affordable option for Realm Object Server?

Tags: ios, realm, cloudkit, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I am an independent iOS app developer with no database experience and little capital. I read about Realm Object Server today and I am interested in setting it up for sync, but I have had little luck figuring out how I can do so in an affordable manner. My app does have a lot of users and a large database, so Amazon AWS EC2 seems like it will become unaffordable very quickly for me. I scoured the web trying to figure out if there was some way to run the Realm Object Server within each user's private CloudKit container, but it seems like that isn't typically done. I could really use some advice on how best deploy Realm Object Server for my particular situation, if anyone can help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a low cost option you could check out [AWS Lightsail](https://amazonlightsail.com/) or [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) both offer $5/month Linux instances and a simpler interface.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I think my issue is that I have no idea how that would scale... I have a database with 15 entities, and a lot of users (to me it's a lot). I just can't tell if it will cost $1 a month per user, etc. (even that would be more than I could afford). I am afraid to commit to something when I can't estimate the cost... any thoughts on what costs might be would be really helpful.

Comment: It does depend on your data transfer but we do estimate ~10k concurrent users on a m4.large instance, which comes out to about $72/month. Your usage could vary but $50-200/month at 10k concurrent users comes out to $0.02 per month per concurrent user on the high end (which might be much less than your MAU given that it is concurrent).